# Checking a Checkbox after checking another one (TreeView)

Tags: c#, treeview

So i have this TreeView with 3 parent nodes, each one with some childs. There's a specific child that depends on others two childs in the same parent node. Here's the code i've done:

```
private void tvMorgan_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Node.Text.Contains("BRL/EUR")) && (e.Node.Parent.Text.Contains("FWD")))
        {
            TreeNode tnParent = e.Node.Parent;
            tnParent.Nodes["BRL/USD"].Checked = true;
            tnParent.Nodes["EUR/USD"].Checked = true;
        }
    }
```

When i run it, it can't find those two nodes i want to check.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by not find?

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside your if, you'll see if your nodes has they KEY you're looking for or if it's just in the Text. Moreover maybe you can make your code less string-dependent.

Comment: You probably forgot to set the TreeNode.Name property.

Answer (score 0):

As commentors pointed out, your nodes are most likely missing a name, which is the **key** used in the string index lookup.  Easy to happen since most nodes get created at runtime.

Simple way to add the name:

```
myParent.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("BRL/USD") { Name = "BRL/USD" });
myParent.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("EUR/USD") { Name = "EUR/USD" });
```

Then your code should work:

```
if (tnParent.Nodes.ContainsKey("EUR/USD"))
  tnParent.Nodes["EUR/USD"].Checked = true;
```

You should probably use the same logic on your `if` condition so that you are less reliant on the text property, which really should be only used for display purposes:

```
if ((e.Node.Name == "BRL/EUR") ...
```

If not setting the names, then you would have to search the node tree yourself to find the "text":

```
TreeNode found = tnParent.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>().Where(x => x.Text.Contains("EUR/USD")).First();
if (found != null)
  found.Checked = true;
```